# Mock method of an object inside function [python]

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have two files:- file1.py and file2.py

file2.py has following code:-

```
import json

def fun1():
    s = "{'function1': 'val1'}"
    s = json.dumps(s)
    print("in fun1 ", s)
    return s

def fun2():
    s = "{'function2': 'value2'}"
    s = json.dumps(s)
    print("in fun2 ", s)
    return s

def fun5():
    fun2()
    return fun1()
```

file1.py has following code

```
from mockito import when, unstub
from file2 import fun5

def mock_the_function():
    when("file2.fun1.json").dumps(...).thenReturn("something something")
    print(fun5())
    unstub()
```

I want to mock "dumps" inside "fun1" only, not "fun2". Code which I have written is showing error. I don't want to do it by parameter comparison. Is there any other way I can have a function being passed inside "when"?

Answer (score 0):

First a quick note:

- `json.dumps` takes an object, not a string, so it's kind of redundant to to call it as you are inside `fun1` and `fun2`.  Perhaps you're looking for `json.loads`?

Next I'd consider some different approaches:

- When you mock `json.dumps`, you want to mock the the `json` property of the `file2` module, so it would just be  `when("file2.json")...` in the setup code for your test.
- Because (as above), we're mocking the `json` module globally in the `file2` module, it's not possible to, as you asked, in that context of a single test, mock `json.dumps` inside of `fun1` but not `fun2`, but what I'd suggest is to simply have two tests, and `unstub` in a tear down method.  For example:

```py
from unittest import TestCase

class TestExample(TestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        unstub()

    def test_fun1(self):
        when("file2.json").dumps(...).thenReturn("something something")
        # in this invocation json is stubbed
        self.assertEqual(fun1(), "something something")

    def test_fun2(self):
        # but now unstub has been called so it won't be stubbed anymore.
        self.assertEqual(fun2(), "...output of fun2...")
```

Another alternative is for `fun1` and `fun2` to take a function that will do the work that the global `json` module is currently doing.  This use of the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dependecy-inversion-principle-solid/) makes the code more testable, and means you don't even need `mockito` in your tests.  For example:

```py
def fun1(json_decoder):
   s = "..."
   return json_decoder(s)

# ....
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def test_fun_1():
   mock_decoder = MagicMock()
   mock_decoder.return_value = "asdf"
   assert fun1(mock_decoder) == "asdf"
```

Comment: 1. Since, everything in python is an object. I think string can be passed inside dumps. But, yeah it's kind of redundant, TBH.I should have taken loads as an example instead of dumps.
2. So, what I am asking for is impossible to implement? I mean that stuff is not possible, right?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, no, I don't believe it's possible to only mock the global json module within `fun1` but not `fun2`.  However, as I mentioned in my answer, there are other ways writing either 1) your functions or 2) your tests that allow allow you to test the behavior you were wanting to test in your question.